# Inserting a GoogleChart in a Wordpress shortcode

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm looking for a way to insert a GoogleChart in a Wordpress page.

I know that shortcode let you add HTML, but what about Javascript? Is this possible?

Let's say I want to add the following example chart:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start

How would I do that? I heard about some plugins that let you add Javascript code in Wordpress, but isn't there a way to do this natively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is!

You'll need to place all those Javascript into its own file and use the theme's functions.php to enqueue the Javascript at the head.

Then inside the Wordpress, edit article as Text and write the div tag as plain HTML.

You can also do it the shortcode way where the shortcode renders that div tag. There is plenty of documentation online to go about this and it is easy to code it. Basically just having a function return that div when the shortcode is called.

Comment: Thanks, I think i get it. Just one thing: where would I use this enqueue function?

Comment: You're welcome, @olivierGrech.  The enqueue function is to be put in the theme's or child theme's functions.php.